# Problems with leaks or 'unregistered class' when returning pointers to derived objects in luabind

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, luabind

I'm exposing the internals of my application to Lua, via luabind, where in C++ I have a `Container` of `shared_ptr<Item>` where `Item` is an abstract base class. Derived classes include `ItemA` and `ItemB`.

To expose these to luabind, I use a couple of wrapper classes (since I want the Container to have a different editing mechanism in the script interface).  I want to be able to enumerate the Items in a Container in a Lua script like this:

```
container=app.container
for i,event in ipairs(container.items) do 
  print(tostring(event))
end
```

The problems I have are that I can expose this functionality by returning raw pointers to `ItemWrappers`, but this leads to memory leaks as the `ItemWrapper` destructors are never called. If I try to declare the wrappers in the luabind as smart pointers [as described in the docs](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#smart-pointers) then this throws a **'Trying to use unregistered class'** exception when I try to return a smart pointer as a lua object.

The wrappers are defined like this:

```
class ContainerWrapper {
public:
   ContainerWrapper(Container& c) : container(c) {};
   Container&  c;  // reference to the actual container
};

class ItemWrapper {
public:
  virtual ~ItemWrapper() {};
  ItemWrapper(int itemIndex_) : itemIndex(itemIndex_) {};
  int   itemIndex;  // items are addressed by index
};

class ItemAWrapper : public ItemWrapper {
public:
  ItemAWrapper(int itemIndex_) : ItemWrapper(itemIndex_) {};
};
```

The luabind registration looks like this: (if I don't use smart pointers)

```
class_<ItemWrapper>("Item") ,
class_<ItemAWrapper, ItemWrapper>("ItemA")
```

and like this if I do:

```
class_<ItemWrapper, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ItemWrapper> >("Item") ,
class_<ItemAWrapper, ItemWrapper, std::tr1::shared_ptr<ItemWrapper> >("ItemA")
```

The function to expose the `items` member of `Container` returns a lua table:

```
luabind::object Container::getItemsAsTable(lua_State* L)
{
  luabind::object table=luabind::newtable(L);
  for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
    table[i+1]= new ItemAWrapper(); // or function to return pointer/smart pointer
  }
  return table;
 }
```

Is this the correct way of setting the value in the table? It's the assignment that generates the exception if I pass a smart pointer, but if I pass a raw pointer then it doesn't seem to assign it into a smart pointer internally and the object gets leaked.  Doing garbage collection doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is already polymorphic. So your `getItemsAsTable` function doesn't need to `new` these `ItemWrapper` objects. Just stick values in it. Like this: `table[i+1] = ItemAWrapper()`. Unless there's something going on where you *need* to use a pointer (like if changing the Lua table should be reflected in C++), don't bother. Just use a value.

Comment: Isn't there a danger of slicing?

Comment: If you return the actual type, then you're not slicing anything. If it's some derived type that's not exposed to Lua, then I would say that you should be exposing that type to Lua.

Comment: How can you return a luabind-registered type by value as a `luabind::object`?

Comment: aha: `luabind::object(L, ItemWrapper())`